# Python 3.0 Windows/COM

Tags: python, com, python-3.x

How to access a COM object from a python file using python 3.0.

And, yes, I know that not a lot of people are using Python 3.0.  Switching back to 2.6 is a *huge* hassle for me, so I don't want to unless I absolutely have to.

I appreciate your time, and any assistance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases) and then create the object using it's progid:

```
import win32com.client
object = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
```

See also the [Python and COM tutorial](http://www.boddie.org.uk/python/COM.html).

EDIT: Hmm... looks like they may not have a python 3.0 version yet.

Comment: Dude, that was awesome.  Lightning quick, too.  :)  

I must have gone to either the wrong SF download page, or an old version of the same proj, or something.  :)  Thanks!