# How to use imported xsensdeviceapi64.dll classes and functions in Python code?

Tags: python, dll, dllimport

From Xsens Device API documentation:

> The C++ interface is not available in compiled form but is provided as part of the SDK as source code that is incorporated in the C header files. This C++ interface code implements a convenience wrapper around the C API. This means that the developer does not have to deal with memory management (i.e. easy object-lifetime management) as the class implementation takes care of this.
>
> The API comprises of two C-interface libraries that are supplied for MS Windows (32 and 64 bit) and Linux. These are:
> XsTypes that contains generic types (vectors, matrices, quaternions, etc.) and some basic operations on those types.Xsens Device API that contains the access to functionality as implemented in Xsens devices. The Xsens Device API library depends on the XsTypes, while XsTypes is an independent library.

So I import `xsensdeviceapi64.dll` to my `Python 3.8.10` code:

```
import os
xda = os.add_dll_directory(r'C:\path\xsensdeviceapi64.dll')
```

However, this line

```
class XdaCallback(xda.XsCallback):
```

throws an error when trying to create a class based on XsCallback Xsens Device API class:

```
builtins.AttributeError: '_AddedDllDirectory' object has no attribute 'XsCallback'
```

XsCallback is a clearly documented Xsens Device API class and I have a working code for Linux (Linux works with a Python wheel file, this code is for Windows) so there is no question about that. I tried also with `xsensdeviceapi_csharp64.dll` and `xsensdeviceapi_com64.dll` which come with the Software Development Kit Windows download, in addition to using an import of `xstypes64.dll` with the `api` imports, but it didn't make any difference. Also renaming the `...dll` files to `...pyd` did not help.

Why doesn't this work? How can I access the API classes and functions in Windows using Python 3.8.10?

Comment: If the manufacturer doesn't provide a library especially written for Python, you have to create your own wrapper with e. g. SWIG or you can try to call the C functions with the `ctypes` module (part of Python standard library).

Comment: @MichaelButscher Could you be a bit more specific? Do I simply add `ctypes()` or something to every function call? SWIG sounds interesting, I'll take a look.

Comment: No, using ctypes needs some knowledge to translate the call signature of a function in C to an appropriate signature in Python with ctypes. Another option may be the COM library in conjunction with pywin32, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710278/python-3-0-windows-com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are wheel files for Python in Movella MTi Products Software Suite. I had downloaded MTw Awinda Software Suite because the project I'm programming for uses MTw sensors and Awinda Dongle.

https://www.movella.com/support/software-documentation